# Silent/Asynchronous gnus-demon?

Tags: gnus, async

Is it possible for gnus-demon to be asynchronous and silent?

I have this:

```
(gnus-demon-add-handler 'gnus-demon-scan-news 5 nil)
```

And every 5 minutes, emacs gets stuck fetching new stuff. Which is annoying.

If `gnus-demon` itself can't do that (and looking at the code, the best I see is the "idle" mode), is there an alternative?

Answer (score 4):

This isn't an solution on how to use async features, but one which will also satisfy your needs, i think.

Basically, you can move the fetching part to an external application, and just read the mails with emacs. Therefore, emacs doesn't have to download them, which should conclude in a non-blocking gnus/emacs. After you've set up the email-retriever, you can just [change](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Mail-Source-Specifiers.html) the way `gnus` gets its emails to a local path.

## IMAP

If you want to use IMAP, I'd suggest to use [`offlineimap`](http://www.offlineimap.org/). It's a small python script, which downloads your mail to a local folder. The [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OfflineIMAP) has also a quite comprehensive documentation for configuring `offlineimap`. An alternative would be [`isync`](http://isync.sourceforge.net/) (which has also an [entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Isync#External_Links) in the ArchWiki)

Additionally, this [guide](http://nakkaya.com/2010/04/10/using-offlineimap-with-gnus/) provides an example configuration file for both `gnus` and `offlineimap`.  (I use Mutt, so this is not my `gnus` config, and can't vouch directly for it.)

## POP3

For POP3, I found [`getmail`](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/), but i have no experience with that.

---

**Additinally** I'd like to point you to this [Gnus Manual entry](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Asynchronous-Fetching.html#Asynchronous-Fetching)

Answer (score 1):

One work around is to have the demon only do stuff when Emacs is idle; I use this:

```
; Demon to fetch email every 5 minutes when Emacs has been idle for 5 minutes:
(gnus-demon-add-handler 'gnus-demon-scan-news 5 5)
```

You will, of course, have to go `g` compulsively in Gnus yourself when Emacs is not idle.

The other thing I do, is that I have one Emacs for Gnus, and another for everything else, i.e. normal editing. (Well, actually, I have a separate Emacs for jabber.el as well).

Emacs is one of the few operating systems in use without "real" multitasking.